# Problem with Clockify API, how to get estimate working again

Tags: clockify

API stopped working last night when creating a project.  Specificly the problem is when you enter a estimate on the project.  This has worked well for months, but now since last night i am getting an error.  Commenting out that line in my code makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

(can't comment...) If you are still having issues with this, if you could post your code and the error message you are getting, I may be able to help you out.